# Is it possible to render TIFF image with QGIS Server?

Tags: qgis-server

I would like to know if QGIS Server is able to render a TIFF Image ?

Actually, I have a QGIS Server running, this server serve correctly my QGIS project to an OpenLayers (java script library) frontend. Images are requested by OpenLayers in PNG, and every things works fine.

Now I would like to get some specific layers in TIFF image containing float32 value. These layers are DEM layers, and I need to get the precise altitude on each pixel (and not a colorscale rgb value). I can't find anywhere in QGIS an option to force this layer to be served in TIFF Float 32 (which is the raw type of my layer's image).

When I look to the GetCapabilities of QGIS Server, I can read :

```
<GetMap>
<Format>image/jpeg</Format>
<Format>image/png</Format>
<Format>image/png; mode=16bit</Format>
<Format>image/png; mode=8bit</Format>
<Format>image/png; mode=1bit</Format>
<Format>application/dxf</Format>
<DCPType>...</DCPType>
</GetMap>
```

So is it possible to add a format in this list ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you're wanting to serve up raw data, which is not what WMS is used for. WMS is used for display, so it'll render the raw TIFF file in the standard image formats that you're seeing here.

What you want to look into is Web Coverage Service (WCS) and apparently, QGIS Server supports this. See: https://docs.qgis.org/2.6/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_ogc/ogc_client_support.html#wcs-client

Alternately, you can get values at a single coordinate by using a WMS GetCapabilities request.

Sounds like you want to get elevation values over an area though, so try WCS.